# I am using Flask and MySQL database but the update query is giving error

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sql-update, flask-mysql

```
myCursor = mydb.connection.cursor() # used flask_mysqldb
    
for i in range(1, session['no_of_questions']+1):
    myCursor.execute("UPDATE " + str.lower(str(quiz_code)) + " SET %s = " + str(selected_answers[i]) +  " where question_code = %s ", (str(session['id'])+"A", str.upper(str(quiz_code))+str(i)))
    myCursor.connection.commit()
myCursor.close()
```

#Error: 1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''9574A' = 2 where question_code = 'CNOP1'' at line 1"

Comment: please _never_ attempt string substitution with SQL statements. as you can see, it's difficult to make it work, and is also vulnerable to SQL-injection attacks. please use the DB-API's recommended method of passing a container as the 2nd argument to `.execute()`.

Comment: myCursor.execute("UPDATE %s SET %s = %s  where question_code = %s ", (str.lower(str(quiz_code)), str(session['id'])+"A", selected_answers[i],  str.upper(str(quiz_code))+str(i)))   ______________  But this is also giving error "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''cnop' SET '9574A' = '2'  where question_code = 'CNOP1'' at line 1